# Does the XP buff from Focused Light stack with Radiant Light?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, completing a Weekly Nightfall Strike awards you a buff for the remainder of the week called "Radiant Light". Radiant Light increases all experience and reputation gained on the character that cleared the Nightfall Strike by 25% until the next Tuesday reset. Recently, there has been a promotion with Red Bull where you can earn an item (Focused Light), which increases experience gained by 50% for 30 minutes.

Do these experience bonuses stack? And, if so, do they stack multiplicative manner (e.g. 1.5 * 1.25 = 1.875) or additive manner (e.g. 0.5 + 0.25 + 1 = 1.75)?

Comment: In my opinion they stack multiplicatively just like all the other modifiers in Destiny. However, there hasn't been an opportunity to stack XP like this before. I believe it is 1.875 (87.5%). I believe that the results round down from fractions. It may be up, so that is why there is going to be a range here: A good way to test would be to get the nightfall + redbull and then win a crucible match. 46 or 47 means 87.5%, 43 or 44 means 75%.

Comment: My only concern is that all the information I can find indicates that Focused Light only increases EXP, not reputation gains. At 20+, unless I'm missing something, those are currently much harder to track.

Comment: Not sure I could be much help testing there. My 3 are at 34. However, I can tell you with certainty that reputations gains are affected by the nightfall.

Comment: That's not how multiplicative stacking works. If it's multiplicative, it will be a 62.5% bonus (1 - (1-.25 * 1 - .5)). If you are doing calculations and multiplicative bonuses are higher that additive, you made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The "Radiant Light" buff only increases xp gain for all activity's, minus the Raids of course. The "Focused Light" promotion will only increase the amount of xp you get, just like the Radiant Light buff. As for it stacking with Radiant Light, I think that it will be able to stack. With reputation, that only goes for vendors and I don't think that it will increase rep gain.

Comment: I'm sorry if it looks like I'm trying to get rep by asking "I hope this helped and all that, but all I'm doing is just trying to help people with problems in destiny.